# Custom alert fadeIn but wont fadeOut

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to make my custom alert fade in and out. I am altering its visibility by adding and removing the class "show" to the toast-container div.It fades in fine however it fades out just momentarily before immediately reappearing again. Using inspect element it shows that it encountered this error:

> job-application-form.php:463 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined
>           at job-application-form.php:463

which is at the function `setTimeout(function(){ cont.classList.remove("show")}, 3000);`and the "show" class was not removed from the div.

I do not understand why I am getting this error or how to fix it. Please help.

Div

```
<div id="toast-container" class="toast-top-right"><div  id="toast-type" class="toast" aria-live="assertive" style=""><div id="snackbar">message</div></div></div>
```

Function:

```
<script> 
  function Toast(message, messagetype) 
  {
     var cont = document.getElementById("toast-container").classList.add("show");
     var type = document.getElementById("toast-type");
     type.className += " " + messagetype;
     var x = document.getElementById("snackbar");
         x.innerHTML = message;
     setTimeout(function(){ cont.classList.remove("show")}, 3000);
  }
</script>
```

Function call in php

```
$Toast = "We have <strong>successfully</strong> received your message and will get back to you as soon as possible.";
        $Error = "toast-error";
        $Success = "toast-success";
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>Toast('$Toast', '$Success');</script>";
```

CSS:

```
#snackbar { 
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

#toast-container {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999999;
    -webkit-animation: fadein 0.5s, fadeout 0.5s 2.5s;
    animation: fadein 0.5s, fadeout 0.5s 2.5s;
}

#toast-container.show {
    visibility: visible;
}

#toast-container * {

    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;

    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;

    box-sizing: border-box;

}

.toast-top-right {

    top: 12px;

    right: 12px;

}

#toast-container > div {

    position: relative;

    pointer-events: auto;

    overflow: hidden;

    margin: 0 0 6px;

    padding: 20px 25px;

    width: 300px;

    -moz-border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;

    -webkit-border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;

    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;

    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 12px #999999;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 12px #999999;

    box-shadow: 0 0 12px #999999;

    color: #FFFFFF;

    opacity: 0.8;

    -ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80);

    filter: alpha(opacity=80);

}

.toast {

    background-color: #030303;

}

.toast-success {

    background-color: #51A351;

}

.toast-error {

    background-color: #BD362F;

}

@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
  from {bottom: 0; opacity: 0;} 
  to {bottom: 30px; opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadein {
  from {bottom: 0; opacity: 0;}
  to {bottom: 30px; opacity: 1;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeout {
  from {bottom: 30px; opacity: 1;} 
  to {bottom: 0; opacity: 0;}
}

@keyframes fadeout {
  from {bottom: 30px; opacity: 1;}
  to {bottom: 0; opacity: 0;}
}
```

Comment: Is your JS getting outputted before you're outputting the `<div id="toast-container"></div>`? You should probably not run that JS until the DOM is fully loaded.

Comment: you try replace cont inside ...settimeout by selector normal document.getElementById("toast-container")

Comment: Your cont variable is undefined within the setTimeout function

Comment: @Magnus no all my Js are loaded at the very end

Comment: @Sk and Sara - That variable should be accessible inside that timeout callback. The problem is most likely what the answer below mentions.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson ok. I agree with Wr1t3r's answer below

Comment: @Sk Ok that works. But why is it not accessible?

Comment: Its not working because function add() isnt returning reference to element.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson not at these state with addclass.. reference..like anwswer i advert the variable is not correct initialized

Comment: @Sk. - That's what I mean. The _variable_ is still accessible, but it's undefined because it's not properly set. addClass doesn't return anything.

Comment: Ok thanks guys, ill accept the answer as soon as the time limit allows me =)

Comment: @DeanStrydom the problem is the selector, the target is distinct ...the addclass ..blurred..the ancestor target

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is in your variable cont which isn't correctly initialized.

Change this line:

```
var cont = document.getElementById("toast-container").classList.add("show");
```

to this:

```
var cont = document.getElementById("toast-container");
cont.classList.add("show");
```

Answer (score 2):

Dean Strydom, you are almost there. Actually, the error message describes exactly the issue.

`var cont = document.getElementById("toast-container").classList.add("show");`
in this line, it is your expectation that **`cont`** is the toast-container but it isn't. It is the result of **`classList.add`** which is just **`undefined`**.

By the time, you use `cont` again to remove the `show` class, it will attempt to access `classList` from `cont` which is in fact `undefined`.

In summary,

```js
var cont = document.getElementById("toast-container");  // simply save this element first
cont.classList.add("show");  // then manipulate afterwards
```

Here is a running snippet. Modified to prompt on button click. Hope this helps you understand the issue better. Just play around the styling/animation.

```js
let animating = false;

function Toast(message, messagetype) {
  var cont = document.getElementById("toast-container");
  cont.classList.add("show");  // correct manipulation
  var type = document.getElementById("toast-type");
  type.className += " " + messagetype;
  var x = document.getElementById("snackbar");
  x.innerHTML = message;
  setTimeout(function() {
    cont.classList.remove("show");  // access it again here
    animating = false;
  }, 3000);
}

let btn = document.querySelector('button');
btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (animating) {
    return;
  }
  animating = true;
  Toast("hi there", "toast-success");
});
```

```css
#snackbar {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

#toast-container {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999999;
  -webkit-animation: fadein 0.5s, fadeout 0.5s 2.5s;
  animation: fadein 0.5s, fadeout 0.5s 2.5s;
}

#toast-container.show {
  visibility: visible;
}

#toast-container * {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.toast-top-right {
  top: 12px;
  right: 12px;
}

#toast-container>div {
  position: relative;
  pointer-events: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 0 6px;
  padding: 20px 25px;
  width: 300px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 12px #999999;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 12px #999999;
  box-shadow: 0 0 12px #999999;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  opacity: 0.8;
  -ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80);
  filter: alpha(opacity=80);
}

.toast {
  background-color: #030303;
}

.toast-success {
  background-color: #51A351;
}

.toast-error {
  background-color: #BD362F;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
  from {
    bottom: 0;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    bottom: 30px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fadein {
  from {
    bottom: 0;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    bottom: 30px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeout {
  from {
    bottom: 30px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    bottom: 0;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeout {
  from {
    bottom: 30px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    bottom: 0;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="toast-container" class="toast-top-right">
  <div id="toast-type" class="toast" aria-live="assertive" style="">
    <div id="snackbar">message</div>
  </div>
</div>
<button>Toast!</button>
```

https://codepen.io/aldnav/pen/gqbEQE

Answer (score 1):

`cont` is not referencing the element you are looking for. `classList.add("show")` does not return anything and in JavaScript if function does not return any thing explicitly, the function by default returns `undefined`. Thus the variable actually holds `undefined` and you get the error.

Try the following:

```
<script> 
  function Toast(message, messagetype) 
  {
    var cont = document.getElementById("toast-container")
    cont.classList.add("show");
    var type = document.getElementById("toast-type");
    type.className += " " + messagetype;
    var x = document.getElementById("snackbar");
    x.innerHTML = message;
    setTimeout(function(){ cont.classList.remove("show")}, 3000);
  }
</script>
```

**Demo of the issue:**

```js
var cont = document.getElementById("toast-container").classList.add("show");
console.log(cont);
```

```css
.show{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="toast-container">Test Container</div>
```